# How to simplify $\sqrt{\sin 2a} + \sin a$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm really stuck and have no idea where to start. I tried double and half angle formulas to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's that??? Plug $a$ into the expression and put it in a calculator!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "solve" ?

Comment: I want a step to step guide to how to simply the expression so it's solvable by using values like $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formula $\boxed{\sin 3x= 3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x}$ and put $x=a$ to find the value of $\sin a$ as the rest to be used in the formula are tabulated, standard values.

Use that value of $\sin a$ to find $\cos a$ and hence $\sin 2a$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin 2a \ge 0$ and $\sin a \le 0$

\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{\sin 2a}+\sin a &= 0 \\
    \sqrt{2\sin a \cos a}+\sin a &= 0 \\
    \sqrt{2\sin a \cos a}+\sin a &= 0 \\
    \sqrt{-\sin a}(\sqrt{-2\cos a}-\sqrt{-\sin a}) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

- $\sin a=0 \implies a=n\pi$
- $\tan a=2 \implies a=(2n+1)\pi+\tan^{-1} 2$

[image]